# Eigenvectors of non-commuting hermitian matrices and quantum mechanics

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, quantum-mechanics

If $A$ and $B$ are Hermitian non-commuting matrices then it is known that they do not have a common eigenbasis. 
However, I believe that it is still true that they may share some eigenvectors. Assume $\vec{x}$ is a normalised common eigenvector of $A,B$ with eigenvalues $\lambda_A, \lambda_B$ respectively. If this is true then,
$$
\vec{x}^\top A^2 \vec{x}= \left(\vec{x}^\top A \, \vec{x}\right)^2= \lambda_A^2 \,, \quad \vec{x}^\top B^2 \vec{x}= \left(\vec{x}^\top B \, \vec{x}\right)^2= \lambda_B^2 \,.
$$
That in turn implies that the variances (e.g. $ Var (A) = \vec{x}^\top A^2 \vec{x}- \left(\vec{x}^\top A\, \vec{x}\right)^2$) of matrices $A$ and $B$ are both zero at the same time.

Now, assuming that what I have mentioned so far is correct and noting that observables in quantum mechanics are represented by Hermitian operators acting on a Hilbert space (let's just focus on the finite dimensional case), how doesn't this contradict the usual intuition from quantum mechanics where it is thought impossible to have states that assign precise values to non-commuting observables?

Is there something wrong in my understanding?

Comment: In the state you are considering the representations of the two observables commute. Because on the state $x$ the observables behave like multiples of the identity.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. However, I do not see how this answers any of my questions. Could you please clarify?

Answer (score 1):

If you have $A$ and $B$ self adjoint operators on an Hilbert space $H$, and $[A,B]$ is a multiple of the identity in the domain $Dom(AB)\cap Dom(BA)$, let's say that $[A,B]_{|Dom(AB)\cap Dom(BA)}= \lambda Id$, then $\forall \psi \in Dom(AB)\cap Dom(BA) $, it holds that $$||A\psi||||B\psi||\geq \frac{|\lambda|}2$$ and 
$$ Var(A,\psi)Var(B,\psi) \geq \frac{|\lambda|^2}4.$$

For the observables position and momentum we have indeed that $\pi([q,p])=i\hbar \ Id$ (Heisenberg commutation relation), so we obtain the well known result that you cite.

In general as in your case, this theorem can be not applicable, or simply $\lambda = 0$ so there is no lower bound on the product of the variances (or there is  a lower bound but this theorem will not tell you).

I hope this will help you. I recommend also to ask this question on https://physics.stackexchange.com/ where IMHO it belongs.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! However, it was not the product that I had in mind. As you correctly say, you can find a state that makes the average commutator zero but that does not imply that the two variances are both zero, only that they bound following from Robertson's inequality is trivial. For example, if you take $A=\sigma_x$ and $B=\sigma_y$ be the two Pauli matrices then the bound in Robertson's inequality becomes 0 for an eigenstate of $\sigma_z$; at the same time it is known that both variances cannot be zero in any state.

Comment: I  don't see what your problem is. The variances in a given state can be both zero even if the two operators do not commute, it is trivial since you can consider  operators that act on a product $H=V_1\oplus V_2$, that sends $V_i\to V_i$ and are the identity on $V_1$ but on $V_2$ they do not commute. The variance for states in $V_1$ will be zero for both, but the operators will not commute on the whole $H$.  What holds for position and momentum may not hold for other observables.  Don't take it badly but if you have a philosophical problem it  is a physics matter not mathematics.

Comment: Regardless of your tone, thanks again for taking the time. I have no philosophical issues (and really not sure how you arrive at this conclusion); what I do suspect I have is a misunderstanding either on the mathematical or physical side of the problem and I am trying to pin it down and hence the question here. Both your first comment and answer did not answer my question.

Comment: Regarding your last comment, are you taking the partial trace on $V_2$? I am a bit confused about what exactly is your construction. What do you mean by "the variances for states in $V_1$ will be zero for both"? If you have an operator acting on $V_1\otimes V_2$, what does average with respect to $V_1$ only give?

Comment: Let $H=V_1\oplus V_2$ (notice that it is not a tensor product it is a direct sum), choose $\tilde{A},\tilde{B}:V_2\to V_2$ self-adjoint that do not commute and define $A,B:H\to H$ as $A|_{V_1} = Id_{V_1}=B|_{V_1}$, and $A|_{V_2} = \tilde{A}$, $B|_{V_2} = \tilde{B}$.
$A$ and $B$ do not commute on $H$ because of their behavior on $V_2$ but if you take $x\in V_1$ then $Var(A,x) = xA^2x-(xAx)^2=0 = Var(B,x) $

Comment: Thank you, that clarifies it.